# Solving ${c_1}^x+\sqrt{\frac{\log(x)x}{2}}+3\log(x)x \le c_2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, logarithms

Is there any way to solve
$${c_1}^x+\sqrt{\frac{\log(x)x}{2}}+3\log(x)x\le c_2,$$

for $x>1$, $0<c_1<1$, and $0<c_2<<1$?

Thanks